# Java UI Framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces

I need some concrete user community experience on whether or not to use prime faces or bootstrap for a java web application that displays charts (KPI Portal) per the following requirements:

Currently using JDK1.7 w/Spring 3.2.2.

- Support for mobile/tablet/web (seamless with little to no code changes to support each device)
- Fast rendering with small payloads over the wire
- Caching
- Binding support for ORM

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: "Fast rendering with small payloads over the wire". You can use HighCharts to do this. JSF generates too big files and a lot of ajax callback to the server

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan cool thanks!  Have you used highcharts? I'm fairly new and was considering/evaluating d3.js or google charts but highcharts looks very clean and visuals are fantastic.

Comment: Yeah I've already use, it's quite easy, fast and have a lot of options! I think that is much better and easier than google charts. But d3 I really don't know yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use Primefaces for this kind of Webapp:

- Support for mobile/tablet/web (seamless with little to no code changes to support each device):

Primefaces provides UI Components for web as well as for mobile devices: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/showcase.jsf
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf

The amount of changes you have to do to get the best result on both devices, depends mostly on  the complexity of your layout. If your Web Content looks much different from your mobile version it´s better to use separated layout files, instead of just rendering certain components in one layout file.

- Fast rendering with small payloads over the wire

You can achieve this by using Primefaces' partialSubmits, lazy loading and default ajax requests. Most components also have a built-in Lazy Loading feature, to increase performance.

- Caching

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with caching. Some components use caching features, e.g. Tabs to avoid an already loaded tab won`t be requested a second time. Sessionmanagement is done by the different Beanscopes like (Sessionscope, or Viewscope).

- Binding support for ORM

It's no problem to combine an object-relational mapping framework, e.g. JPA with JSF.